# Modifying button header from collectionview cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am writing and order app for iOS,In the title I was not very explanatory, but the pictures let me tell you what I want to do.

[image] [image]

In the first picture I have a "status" button in a collectionview object's zero cell (OrderDetailZeroCell).When I click this button, the second picture shows a launcher (selection list opens).When I select the title from the cell I selected from the dropdown list, I want to change the status of the status button (for example, on the road, preparing it.).

Thank you.

Comment: From what I understand, you are trying to change some ViewController Button label according to the title from the cell?

Comment: It would be helpful if you would upload some code

Comment: Yes @VadimF.  I'll add a code.

Comment: I've had a mistake in the answer, edited it

Answer (score 0):

If the UICollectionView isn't in another class (Though it should be..), this code should work:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    yourButton.setTitle("\(yourCellArray[indexPath.row].title)", for: .normal)

}
```

Let me know if it did it.

Comment: i tried like that; stat.statusButton.setTitle("\(cellArray[indexPath.row])", for: .normal)
        print("\(cellArray[indexPath.row])")

It seem working in print. Bu i need change my button title.Its not working on my button